# Display a post via template

Tags: posts, templates, sidebar

I want to display a single post in the sidebar-area (not the sidebar itself) and can't seem to get it working.
I know the post_id (it's 1571 btw), so I looked around and only found this link from 7 years ago: [Display Posts from a specific Category in the Sidebar](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-posts-from-a-specific-category-in-the-sidebar)

So after looking around, I found the useful functions "get_posts()" and "get_post()".
First one requires an array which is not what I want as it is a single post.
Second one.. well that's where I am so far:

```
<?php get_post('1571');?>
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

**edit01:**
I am able to display the post's title by using

`$post_id_1 = get_post($my_id);` 
`echo $post_id_1->post_title;`

Comment: Since you're able to get the post title ( [and other post object attributes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) ), what else are you trying to do that you need help with? What is your specific question?

Comment: Please do not abuse the php tag. :-)

Comment: abuse? me? Nah : P
I'm still learning the ropes of PHP so coding a template is hard work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_post()` returns a post object. So you can try the following

```
$post = get_post( 1571 );
setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title();
    the_content();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: My pleasure. Off to the weekend now :-). Enjoy